# using awk and logical operators to filter multiple columns in shell script

Tags: shell, awk

I have to filter multiple columns:

```
1) File should have the word "Cat" or "Dog" 
2) Column 6 should be TRUE
3) Column 7 should be more than 7
```

I did:

```
awk -F',' '$5~/Cat/ || $5~/Dog && $6=="TRUE" && $7>=7' cat.csv > catFinal.csv
```

What i need is, after whichever part of the first condition is true, the next true conditions should be applied.

Comment: [edit] your question to include concise, testable sample input and expected output and tell is if you're trying to do a partial match or a full match and whether you want regexp or string matching for each value (e.g. if the word `Catastrophe` appears in a line - does that match `Cat`? Does `Cat` match `C.t`)?. Why does item 1 say `_File_ should have,..` while items 2 and 3 identify specific fields - can `Cat` appear anywhere on the line? Also tell us what problem are you having with the script you posted? Is it the syntax error you're asking for help with? See [ask].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple solution is to group the first two tests for `Cat` or `Dog` into a single regular expression so your total conditional is a 3-component AND, e.g. `test1 && test2 && test3`. You can do that with:

```
 awk -F, '$5~/(Cat|Dog)/ && $6=="TRUE" && $7>=7' cat.csv > catFinal.csv
```

Which will ensure all aspects of the test are applied to each record. The conditionals are applied left-to-right, so as it was written, you would match any records where `$5~/Cat/` or records where `$5~/Dog && $6=="TRUE" && $7>=7` were true.